# Python-rsa: can encrypt cannot decrypt

Tags: python, encryption, aes, rsa

**New rephrased Question**

There are two programs that work together, a client and a server.

The client is having issues decrypting, and i have ran the following test on the client without any server interaction and this does not work.

I get `rsa.pkcs1.DecryptionError: Decryption failed` when i run this code on the client.

```
# Public key saved in ini file as this format "PublicKey(n, e)"
# Private key saved in ini file as this format "PrivateKey(n, e, d, p, q)"

key_string = public_key.strip("PublicKey(").strip(")")
n, e = key_string.split(", ", 1)
value = rsa.encrypt(b"Hello", public_key)

key_string = self.private_key.strip("PrivateKey(").strip(")")
n, e, d, p, q = key_string.split(", ", 4)
private_key = rsa.PrivateKey(int(n), int(e), int(d), int(p), int(q))
decrypted = rsa.decrypt(value, private_key)
```

**Old "Question" asked**

---

> I am writing a python program that is essentially a P2P chat
> application utilising a rendezvous server for new connections.
>
> Walkthrough of the steps taken by client/server.
>
> Client:
>
> - Connects to server using sockets
> - Sends its public key to server
>
> Server:
>
> - Reads public key
> - Creates AES key and ciphers a message (list of already connected peers)
> - Encrypts the AES Key using the clients RSA public key
> - Sends the key and ciphertext
>
> Client:
>
> - Reads the information and splits into the key portion and the ciphertext portion
> - **Decrypts the AES Key (However this fails even though the same code works on the server to decode)**
> - Decrypts the cipher text using the now unencrypted AES Key
>
> ````
> # Encrypt with AES cipher_text, key, nonce = self.aes.encrypt(json.dumps(message))
> # Encrypt AES Key with RSA encrypted_key = self.rsa.encrypt(key, peer['public_key'])
>
> # Send data to peer self.socket.sendto(encrypted_key + nonce + cipher_text, peer['address']) ```
>
> ``` CLIENT CODE
>
> data, address = self.socket.recvfrom(65536) recv = {"key": data[:256],
> "nonce": data[256:272], "data": data[272:]}
>
> key = self.rsa.decrypt(recv["key"]) peers =
> json.loads(self.aes.decrypt(recv["data"], key, recv["nonce"])) ```
> ````

Comment: What kind of error/exception does it throw? Can you provide some more info? It might be you're badly receiving/sending the encrypted AES key via the socket, since server-side it works.

Comment: packages\rsa\pkcs1.py", line 282, in decrypt
raise DecryptionError("Decryption failed")
rsa.pkcs1.DecryptionError: Decryption failed

Comment: Looking into that error this is where it is breaking.

pkcs1.py:
# If we can't find the cleartext marker, decryption failed.
cleartext_marker_bad = not compare_digest(cleartext[:2], b"\x00\x02")

Comment: Are you sure you're slicing the data stored in the dictionary correctly, client side?

Comment: I've printed it out along with the type on each end, both being identical

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Just checked this with a `md5_hash.hexdigest()` and comes out identical before and after sending.

Comment: are you sure the output of self.rsa.encrypt is 256 bytes?  are you using rsa encryption with padding or authentication implementations?

Comment: I have done len() on the encrypted output and both client and server sides show 256.

I am using Pythons rsa module using the line `rsa.encrypt(value, public_key)` not sure if this is padding or auth implementations

Comment: Just did another test, a basic encrypt/decrypt on the client side without sockets also fails.


`encrypted = self.rsa.encrypt(b"Hello", self.config.public_key)
print(encrypted)
print(self.rsa.decrypt(encrypted))`

Answer (score 1):

Solved this, Thanks for the help!

The error was with my import of the config file, my statement was checking if there was a valid RSA-pub/priv key and if there wasn't it would generate a new pair for the user.

The problem was it was always generating a new keypair. meaning it was attempting to decrypt with the incorrect private key.